# Case where an orthogonal projection matrix becomes a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, regression, projection, projection-matrices

Let $A$ be a tall $m \times n$ matrix with full column rank. Let $m \times m$ matrix

$$H=[h_{ij}] = A(A'A)^{-1}A'$$

denote the orthogonal projection onto the column space of $A$. I know that $0 \leq h_{ii} \leq 1$ for all $i = 1,2,\dots,m$, i.e., all the diagonal elements of projection matrix $H$ should be between $0$ and $1$.

I'm wondering in which case $H$ matrix is a given diagonal matrix $D$. In other words, what restriction on matrix $A$ will lead to a conclusion that $H=D$, where $D$ is given?

Comment: What is the orthogonal projection of a matrix?

Comment: Its defined as $A(A’A)^{-1}A’$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me any advice what the form of A should be?

Comment: If $A$ is truly arbitrary, then $A'A$ might not be invertible, in which case the expression $A(A'A)^{-1}A'$ is undefined.

Comment: If $H$ is diagonal, what does that say about its image?

Comment: I tried QR decomposition of a rectangular matrix A, instead of SVD. $A=QR=[Q_{1},Q_{2}]R$, where $Q=m\times m$ unitary matrix and $R$, $m\times n$ rectangular matrix. $Q_{1}$ is the first $n$ column of Q, $Q_{2}$ is the last $(m-n)$ column of Q. Then $H=P(A)=Q_{1}Q_{1}'$. Honestly, the result that I'm looking for is $M(A)=I-P(A)=I-H=D$, where $M$ is the annihilator matrix and $D$ is a GIVEN diagonal. So using that, $M=Q_{2}Q_{2}'=D$ is what I want. I'm looking for what condition of A will guarantee such a conclusion that $M=Q_{2}Q_{2}'=D$, FOR A CERTAIN $D$. ($D$ is given.)

Comment: I guess $A$ should be somehow related to $D$, where $A$ is $m\times n$ and $D$ is $m\times m$. Can you give me any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your formula to make sense, $A$ must have linearly independent columns.  We therefore assume that this is the case.

$H$ will be diagonal if and only if $A$ has an invertible [$n \times n$ submatrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Submatrix.html) and $A$ has zeros in all entries outside this submatrix.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If I want $H$ want to be a CERTAIN (or GIVEN) $m \times m$ diagonal matrix, what would be the restriction on $n\times n$  submatrix of $A$?

Comment: I thought I didn't specify what I wanted, so I wrote another post : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833611/case-where-a-residual-maker-or-annihilator-matrix-becomes-a-certain-diagonal-m.

Answer (score 0):

Where the columns of $X_{n \times p}$ are orthogonal. You have used $H$ to denote the projection matrix, so I guess the domain is regression analysis. So, when the columns of $X$ are orthogonal, that is algebraic implication of pairwise independent random variables, then $X'X = I_p$, thus 
$$
X(X'X)^{-1}X'=XI_p^{-1}X'=XX'= I_n.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, it's about regression analysis. Actually, the projection matrix $H$ needs to be a certain form, such that $I-D$, where $D$ is a given diagonal matrix. I guess I didn't specify what I want. So I wrote another post, please refer to this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833611/case-where-a-residual-maker-or-annihilator-matrix-becomes-a-certain-diagonal-m

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ be tall and have full column rank. Let $\rm A = U \Sigma V^\top$ be its [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition) (SVD). Let

$$\rm A \,\big( A^\top A \big)^{-1} A^\top = \cdots = U \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_n & \mathrm O\\ \mathrm O & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix} U^\top$$

be the $m \times m$ projection matrix that projects onto the column space of $\rm A$. Therefore, if $\rm U$ is an $m \times m$ [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix), i.e., if the $n$-dimensional column space of $\rm A$ is spanned by $n$ of the $m$ vectors in the standard basis of $\mathbb R^m$, then the projection matrix will be diagonal with diagonal entries $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I didbn't specify what I needed in the post. Sorry for inconvenience. I want $H$ to be a specific given diagonal matrix $D$, where the elements of $D$ is bounded between zero and one. But this $D$ is given. Given $D$, I want to reconstruct the form of $A$.